# Django - Form dropdown list from database not updated immediately after adding new

Tags: python, django, forms

I am new to Django and am stuck. I have a model sample below -

```
class Machines(models.Model):
    machine_name = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True, unique=True)
```

And associated form -

```
class NewMachine(forms.Form):
    machine_name = forms.CharField(label="Machine Name",required=True)
```

Now I am using this model values (names of machine) in a dropdown in another form with -

```
all_machines = [i['machine_name'] for i in Machines.objects.values('machine_name').distinct()]
machine_choices = [(i,i) for i in get_uniq_obj(all_machines)]
machine_name = forms.MultipleChoiceField(required=False,
                     choices=machine_choices,label="")
```

`get_uniq_obj` is just a function that removes duplicates further. 
The problem is I don't see newly added machine names (from Machines table) in the form dropdown list immediately, or until I restart the server.

I tried to put the `all_machines` block in various locations but the STDOUT does not go to this code path again for it to load the new values for dropdown from the database.

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't do that. Use `ModelMultipleChoiceField` with the queryset parameter.

Comment: Thanks! Used the queryset to get the data I needed!!

Comment: I am getting “XXXX is not a valid value for a primary key" error for drop down in form. Any idea why?